# Filtered Datasource doesn't require me to use the dataview instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dataview, rowfilter

When I need to add filter to a datasource , I normally do :

```
var dv= dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "id=1";
xxx.DataSource = dv.ToDable();
xxx.DataBind();
```

But I've tried to do it without the dataview instance And I got pretty weird results:

I created a datatable :

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable("myTable");
   dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof (int));
   dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof (string));
   DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
   row["id"] = 1;
   row["name"] = "aaa";
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
   row = dt.NewRow();
   row["id"] = 2;
   row["name"] = "222";
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Then added a RowFilter

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "id=1";
```

And then I displayed the datatable on the screen ( simple loop) I saw this :

[image]

So the RowFilter did not has any affect. ( obviously because we didn't do it through the DataView instance).

**But**

when I binded it to a DropDownList **it did consider** the Rowfilter !

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.DataSource=dt; //notice I don't use the dataview instance
ddl.DataTextField="name";
ddl.DataValueField="id";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Test :

`ddl.Items.Count` was 1

But I can't find any documentation for that test.

**Question :**

Does `DataBind()` allow me to create filtered datasource **without** using the dataview Instance (e.g. : does setting  RowFilter is sufficient)?

Comment: What is `xxx`? gridview? did you called databind() after setting datasource?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes I did call `DataBind()` ( edited.) and xxx is an acceptable datasource container. it could be repeater / ddl / ....

Comment: I just tried binding with gridview, It works fine. shows `id = 1` only. not sure how you're trying

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you didn't understand my question. It seems that databind does consider the rowfilter ( and not via dataview) while iterating the datasource with a loop does not consider the rowfilter.

Comment: So grid is displaying 1 only but when you loop you get 2 records. is this your question?